# Top Questions of the Week #9

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post 9 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and it's contents.

Answer (score 8):

Another possiblity is this question:

> [What is "flashing the BIOS"?](https://superuser.com/questions/126149/what-is-flashing-the-bios)

I'm aware that this is my question, however it is a commonly misunderstood topic and severe consequences can occur if not carried out properly...

I'm not suggesting this because it was my question or to get myself/my question more publicity, I would recommend this, regardless of user...

Answer (score 4):

It's quite common for Super Users to reinstall their operating systems. This question about finding out the Serial Keys of the software installed should come in handy for those reinstalling them

[How can I get the product keys for software on my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/176306/is-there-a-product-key-finder-for-a-pc)