# Are you interested in writing blog posts?

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog

After the blog [*became officially blessed by Jeff Atwood*](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2153/the-super-user-blog-now-officially-blessed) we've got some weekly posts and daily traffic on it, with an occasional spike on some of the most interesting blog posts. However, anyone with a keen eye might have spotted that it was mostly the same team of blog editors writing posts. Some of them are busy these days, others have burned out. It has been a great start, *but we don't want it to stop there...*

There have been quite some posts about our [Question of the Week](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2249/super-user-questions-of-the-week-9) on Monday, an extensive review of Kingston SSDs (thank you Kingston!) and interviews to put our very own users in the spotlight. We've also seen some posts from our various categories, like Productivity matters on Thursday and of course our weekly WTFriday about strange / odd / fun Super User stuff…

**The purpose of the Super User Community Blog is to highlight what *you* want to see.**

While we're somewhat forced to be on-topic and concise on the site to keep our quality at high standards; on the blog we have more "artistic freedom" to add context and explain things further. Stories and subjective thoughts are welcome too – as long as they are in the form of a few paragraphs.

We are always excited to bring new writers and editors to the Super User Community Blog; so, if you are interested in contributing, please [let us know](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/356/super-user-blog-editor-room)! We emphasize that the blog is *from* and *for* the community:

### [Are *you* interested in writing blog posts? Check this blog post out!](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/09/are-you-interested-in-writing-for-our-blog/)

This will allow us to cover the full breadth of Super User and also that every aspect gets the same attention. There is a broad spectrum of topics to write about: Preferably about your favorite or best Super User question/answer; a product review, your favorite backup tool or just some [crazy Super User-ish technical story](https://superuser.com/questions/231273/what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for)!

The blog editors will proofread and schedule the submitted posts for you; we can give you access to the necessary blog services after you've shows us a draft, it's as easy as [starting to write](https://docs.google.com/) and [sharing it](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/356/super-user-blog-editor-room).

If you have any further questions, feel free to ask them here or come to our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115/stack-exchange-community-blogs). Although we can't be there day and night, feel free to leave us a message and we'll try to ping you once we pass along.

<sub>As Jeff mentioned in his post, I'm able to officially subsidize hardware purchases for writing great blog entries, so we'll be able to do a lot more interesting stuff in the future! Furthermore, frequent blog editors who write at least three high-quality posts will receive a free Super User t-shirt (with my approval).</sub>

Comment: Woo Hoo!!!  More minions to do @IvoFlipse bidding!

Comment: @KronoS: and my bidding as well...

Comment: @studiohack you scare me :p

Comment: Is it too late to submit posts?

Comment: It's never too late :-) Rather, its an ongoing process of getting more writers, so hopefully we can start posting multiple posts per day! So keep the submissions coming

Comment: Is there a reputation requirement to be able to post?  I'm a fairly conservative person and only answer questions which I want to answer, not what I could.  I love writing articles, and posts, but do not want to even submit, if at 1k reputation I'm not considered enough of a 'user' to do this.

Comment: There is not @zackrspv, feel free to drop into our chatroom and we'll work something out :-)

Comment: A good tip : when you find "Once upon a time" on metauser answer with more than 500 upvotes, it's a good sign you found a good article subject. Now you must write it !..

Answer (score 4):

It is never too late to submit blog posts - this is an ongoing effort.  If you have a blog post to submit, post a link to it hosted elsewhere (Google Docs, Skydrive/Office Webapps, etc) in the **[Super User Blog Editor Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/356/super-user-blog-editor-room)** and a blog admin/editor will get back with you within a few days.