# Looking for users to write about their (fun) experiences for the Super User Blog!

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog

[The Super User Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/) is getting organized! Several weekly categories have been set up and we're looking for awesome things to write about! WTFriday is a brand new section that should produce an awesome post for The Super User Blog every single friday! WTFriday is about everything, it’s about (good or bad) experiences, it’s about frustrations, rants and praises, it’s about you and most of all it’s about the “fun” side of computer stuff!

For WTFriday, I'm looking for users who are willing to write about a recent (or less recent for that matter) fun experience they've had with computers!

***(Sys-admins, we're probably looking for you!)***

For example, if you're a sys-admin and have to deal with questions about the "<kbd>any</kbd>"-key daily, write about it! The sky is pretty much the limit on this one!

[image: We wantYOU!]

If you’re eager to write about something you’ve experienced or if you’ve been working on an awesome project (We’ve got one in store for you! It involves a CPU and the apocalypse! Keep checking the blog for more!) contact me through this meta post or e-mail. My e-mail address be "**Bloodphilia at gmail dot com**".

[As per the blog "rules"](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2278/the-super-user-blog-is-looking-for-writers), *frequent blog authors who write at least three high-quality posts will receive a free Super User t-shirt* (with IvoFlipse's approval)! ;) So get writing and let me know!

<sub>Publication is not guaranteed, your draft will be reviewed and edited if deemed necessary.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

It is never too late to submit blog posts - this is an ongoing effort.  If you have a blog post to submit, post a link to it hosted elsewhere (Google Docs, Skydrive/Office Webapps, etc) in the **[Super User Blog Editor Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/356/super-user-blog-editor-room)** and a blog admin/editor will get back with you within a few days.

Comment: isn't this a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @Yar Isn't that a question and not a comment?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question

Comment: Isn't that a link and not an answer? (sorry, could not resist)

Comment: @Mahn http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_control

Comment: @Yar thank you good sir, I am a new person now.