# Top Questions of the Week #23

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into week 23 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about, it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Comment: Note to the answerers, if you dig a question, you can always submit a draft blog post about it, even if its **not** picked as QotW

Comment: Ivo is completely right here: you are _always_ welcome to submit a blog post about any SU question or related topic you find interesting. QotW is a way for us to highlight high-quality content on Super User, but the blog is open to anybody who wants to participate!

Comment: Where do you submit a draft blog post?

Comment: @JamesFaile check out the information at http://blog.superuser.com/contribute/ for details about how to submit blog posts. You can also visit the [Blog Editors Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/356/super-user-blog-editor-room) to ask any questions you might have.

Comment: Due to all of the great suggestions this week, I'll also point out that we can have one question of the week winner, but write about several questions, or write about them next week if nothing else wins.

Comment: We need more diversity.  All these superuser questions.  I demand some affirmative action for software developers!!

Comment: @surfasb you do realize this is the _Super User Blog_, right?

Comment: Oops,I thought this was a stackexchange blog :|

Comment: Nope, this blog is just for SU. If you go to http://blogoverflow.com/ you can find blogs for other Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Where do deleted items go on the hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/301364/where-do-deleted-items-go-on-the-hard-drive/301405#301405) has a "particularly bloggable topic" that made me think a lot about the subject.  I submitted an answer, but it wasn't accepted - so I'm not too worried about popularity.

Comment: Posted here as per your suggestion, nhinkle.

Comment: Thanks James. I deleted your answer on the other question, to keep things in the right place.

Comment: James, would you be interested in blogging about this?

Comment: Sure, I'll draft something up and link it to you in the chat room.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your contributions.

Answer (score 8):

The following question is interesting, and the answers get into some interesting facts about how email and DNS work:

## Why can't I email myself at: MyEmail@74.125.235.55?

> I opened cmd and typed ping gmail.com
> it shows me
>
> ```
> Pinging gmail.com [74.125.235.55] with 32 bytes of data:
> Reply from 74.125.235.55: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=56
> ```
>
> I have a GMail account, so I emailed
> myself but instead of email@gmail.com
> I used email@74.125.235.55
>
> However I did not receive the email,
> does anyone know why is it so?
>
> Why can't I just substitute the
> gmail.com part with 74.125.235.55?

Comment: I thought that was a really cool question, definitely learned quite a bit from it about DNS.

Comment: Link to the question: http://superuser.com/questions/306995/why-cant-i-email-myself-at-myemail74-125-235-55

Answer (score 7):

I thought that [What Makes a Laptop Overheat](https://superuser.com/questions/306120/what-makes-a-laptop-overheat) was a very good question this week. It's something we all should be concerned about, and overheating we may encounter one day. I think though if it was written about, it should be more about how to protect from overheating, and proper cooling, as well as keeping the system in check.

I could write about it as I have rather improper cooling, might be a lesson for me.

Answer (score 7):

Wow! Super User is full of great questions this week!

## [How does a CPU 'know' what commands and instructions actually mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/307116/how-does-a-cpu-know-what-the-commands-mean)

resulted in some great explanations about how microprocessors work. I'd be interested in seeing a post about this later, regardless of whether it gets chosen as the QotW. If anybody's interested in writing that, let me know.

Comment: I would personally like to see this blogged.

Answer (score 4):

Moved from the QotW from last week:

Just stumbled upon [this](https://superuser.com/questions/306625/how-does-a-computer-know-which-cd-dvds-to-boot-from) question about how a computer selects the drive to boot up from. I think it might be a good question given we just covered how a computer actually reboots.

Answer (score 0):

> I have encountered a very strange behavior in Windows 7 that I cannot seem to identify and I have never seen or heard of on any system configuration. Whenever I move my mouse to the left-most edge of my primary display (centered in 3-display setup), my desktop icons magically move away from the cursor (up or down and to the right). It only happens when my mouse is positioned on the edge of the main display and moving the mouse all the way to the right edge of my right secondary display causes the mouse icons to snap back into position.

[Magical moving desktop icons](https://superuser.com/questions/307377/magical-moving-desktop-icons)

Comment: Hah, what?! This might be a good candidate for [WTFriday](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2537/looking-for-users-to-write-about-their-fun-experiences-for-the-super-user-blog).

Comment: I think it should be a Windows 8 "feature"